# ActiveRecord return glitch values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the code:

```
Product.find_by_sql("SELECT pr.*,
                        CASE en.name
                          WHEN NULL THEN pr.name
                          ELSE en.name
                        END AS name,
                        CASE en.short_descr
                          WHEN NULL THEN pr.short_descr
                          ELSE en.short_descr
                        END AS short_descr,
                        CASE en.full_descr
                          WHEN NULL THEN pr.full_descr
                          ELSE en.full_descr
                        END AS full_descr,
                        CASE en.meta_keys
                          WHEN NULL THEN pr.meta_keys
                          ELSE en.meta_keys
                        END AS meta_keys,
                        CASE en.meta_descr
                          WHEN NULL THEN pr.meta_descr
                          ELSE en.meta_descr
                        END AS meta_descr
                        FROM products AS pr
                        LEFT JOIN entities AS en ON en.resourcable_id = pr.id AND
                          (en.resourcable_type = 'Product'
                          OR en.resourcable_type = 'ProductEx'
                          OR en.resourcable_type = 'ProductGd'
                          OR en.resourcable_type = 'ProductOd'
                          OR en.resourcable_type = 'ProductQt'
                          OR en.resourcable_type = 'ProductRt'
                          OR en.resourcable_type = 'ProductTk')
                        WHERE pr.name LIKE '%condom%' OR
                          pr.short_descr LIKE '%condom%' OR
                          pr.full_descr LIKE '%condom%';")
```

But then I execute this code, I have some glitch values. For example, I have `product` with `name`, but `Postman` shows me that the `name` is `null`. And second, in my query where are some extra `products` which shouldn't be there.

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's the query itself which is faulty - if you execute the query outside of rails (eg in your database's query browser) do you see the same results?

Comment: There is very little for us to go up on to help you. You need to provide more information. What does the query result from the db show as opposed to what Rails gives you?

Comment: then I execute this in `postgresql`, I have normal names, but there are redundant values in database too